# Calculating the load on the end of a beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, beam, deflection

We ordered a really nice light for our dinner table and ordered a special "lightswing" seperatly.
The light that we ordered however is heavier than the 'lightswing' is rated for.

Please see the picture for some clarification.

The grey part is our ceiling. The light swing is rated to handle 3.5 kg at a 80cm extension.
My question is how do I calculate the maximum weight when the light swing is only extended lets say 50 cm?

I tried to Google but could not figure out the right way to calculate this.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic rule of thumb would say,

$$80* 3.5 =P*50 \quad P= 80*3.5/50 = 1.6*3.5= 5.6 kg$$

- P is the light fixture weight

but the fastners attaching the hanger to the ceiling need to be strong enough to support this load too.